# curl: (7) Failed connect to 192.168.169.128:80; Connection refused, how to fix?

Tags: nginx, haproxy

Why is my haproxy load balancer not working?

I'm on centos 7.

I've set up 2 servers "nginx-node01" and "nginx-node02". As the name implies these 2 servers are of nginx. They're up and running.

The server's IP address being 192.168.169.133(hostname=nginx-node01) and 192.168.169.135(hostname=nginx-node02) respectively.

Then I've set up haproxy on another server.
It's IP address being 192.168.169.128(hostname=haproxy-centos8). (I'm on centos 7, ignore the hostname centos8)

When I do curl 192.168.169.128 in haproxy server, I get:

```
curl: (7) Failed connect to 192.168.169.128:80; Connection refused
```

This is what I've done so far:

1. Configure the /etc/hosts files in haproxy server.

vi /etc/hosts and add the following lines there

```
   192.168.169.128 haproxy-centos8
   192.168.169.133 nginx1.loadbalancer.me  nginx-node01
   192.168.169.135 nginx2.loadbalancer.me  nginx-node02
```

Save the file and exit the editor.

2. Go to hosts file on /etc/hosts on nginx-node01 and paste the following lines:

   ```
    192.168.169.128  haproxy-centos8
    192.168.169.133  nginx-node01
    192.168.169.135  nginx-node02
   ```

Do the same for nginx-node02

3. Go to haproxy-centos8 server.
   Edit haproxy.cfg file like this:

   ```
    #---------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Global settings
    #---------------------------------------------------------------------
    global
        log         127.0.0.1 local2     #Log configuration

        chroot      /var/lib/haproxy
        pidfile     /var/run/haproxy.pid
        maxconn     4000                
        user        haproxy             #Haproxy running under user and group "haproxy"
        group       haproxy
        daemon

        # turn on stats unix socket
        stats socket /var/lib/haproxy/stats

    #---------------------------------------------------------------------
    # common defaults that all the 'listen' and 'backend' sections will
    # use if not designated in their block
    #---------------------------------------------------------------------
    defaults
        mode                    http
        log                     global
        option                  httplog
        option                  dontlognull
        option http-server-close
        option forwardfor       except 127.0.0.0/8
        option                  redispatch
        retries                 3
        timeout http-request    10s
        timeout queue           1m
        timeout connect         10s
        timeout client          1m
        timeout server          1m
        timeout http-keep-alive 10s
        timeout check           10s
        maxconn                 3000

    #---------------------------------------------------------------------
    #HAProxy Monitoring Config
    #---------------------------------------------------------------------
    listen haproxy3-monitoring *:8080                #Haproxy Monitoring run on port 8080
        mode http
        option forwardfor
        option httpclose
        stats enable
        stats show-legends
        stats refresh 5s
        stats uri /stats                             #URL for HAProxy monitoring
        stats realm Haproxy\ Statistics
        stats auth howtoforge:howtoforge            #User and Password for login to the monitoring dashboard
        stats admin if TRUE
        default_backend app-main                    #This is optionally for monitoring backend

    #---------------------------------------------------------------------
    # FrontEnd Configuration
    #---------------------------------------------------------------------
    frontend main
        bind *:80
        option http-server-close
        option forwardfor
        default_backend app-main

    #---------------------------------------------------------------------
    # BackEnd roundrobin as balance algorithm
    #---------------------------------------------------------------------
    backend app-main
        balance roundrobin                                     #Balance algorithm
        option httpchk HEAD / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:\ localhost    #Check the server application is up and healty - 200 status code
        server nginx-node01 192.168.169.133:80 check                 #Nginx1 
        server nginx-node02 192.168.169.135:80 check                 #Nginx2
   ```
4. Then configure rsyslog for HAProxy.

Edit this file

```
vi /etc/rsyslog.conf
```

Uncomment this line to enable the UDP connection:

```
$ModLoad imudp
$UDPServerRun 514
```

If you want to use a specific IP, you can add a new line like the one below:

```
$UDPServerAddress 127.0.0.1
```

Save the file and exit

5. Then create new haproxy configuration file for rsyslog:

   cd /etc/rsyslog.d/
   vi haproxy.conf

Paste configuration below:

```
local2.=info     /var/log/haproxy-access.log    #For Access Log
local2.notice    /var/log/haproxy-info.log      #For Service Info - Backend, loadbalancer
```

Then I did things like restarting rsyslog, starting haproxy, enabling haproxy etc. My nginx was already configured.

Comment: `connection refused` indicates that nothing is listening on that port. Use `ss -tnlp` to check if haproxy is actually running and listening on the correct interface. Further, your information does not match up. Sometimes you have `192.168.169.X`, sometimes `192.168.1.X`. Make sure you have the correct subnet configured everywhere.

Comment: That's a typo, I've edited the post now.

Comment: `users:(("haproxy",pid=1049,fd=5))
LISTEN      0      128                  *:111                              *:*                   `

This is the output of ss -tnlp

Comment: It is not listening on port 80 or 8080. You are probably editing the wrong config file.

Comment: I'm 100% sure I'm not editing the wrong conf file. I've done these steps multiple times again and again!

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I did nothing and it fixed itself.

Comment: You did something. You may not know what, but I'm rather certain it's something.

Comment: the another thing is - why use haproxy for LB, nginx can do that no problem for http or tcp using configurable strategies.   Back to the question, before posting the question it's better to analyze logs from the systemd service unit and application log itself. (in this case, haproxy) Is it even started and not crashed? apparmor? Firewall?